# Prime Ideal of a Polynomial Ring

Tags: ring-theory

I am wondering how to show that the ideal (x,y) is prime and maximal in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Comment: Look at the ring homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\varphi(f)=f(0,0)$. What is the kernel of this map?

Comment: @Prometheus: the kernel is exactly (x,y) and the image of the homomorphism is Q, and then using the first isomorphism to conclude that (x,y) is maximal because Q[x,y]/(x,y) is a field

Answer (score 9):

Look at the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x,y)$. Then use that an ideal $I \subset R$ is maximal iff $R/I$ is a field. Using the fact that $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain, you will also be able to show that $(x,y)$ is prime (and all maximal ideals are).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ (excerpted from one of my old posts - which shows even more)

> Even  easier: $\ \,$  the ideals $\rm\ \ (x)\:\ \subset (x,y)\ \subset\ (1)\ $ are distinct primes$\ \ \, $  [or $(1)$]
> since their residue rings $\rm\, \mathbb Q[y]\ \supset\ \ \ \mathbb Q\ \ \ \ \supset\ (0)\ $ are distinct domains [or $(0)$]

Comment: Why is this easier: is it not exactly equivalentto what was proposed by Sebastian and by Prometheus  in his comment?

Comment: @Mariano: You misunderstand: the "easier" refers to the post from where it was excerpted.

Comment: Similarly for  $(p)\subset (p,x) \subset (1)=\Bbb Z[x]\,$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/666569/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ such that $(x,y) \subsetneq I \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.  Choose $a \in I$ with $a \not \in (x,y)$.  Then $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and we conclude $I = \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ (why?) and $(x,y)$ is maximal.

Now let $F, G \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ with $FG \in (x,y)$.  Note $F$ and $G$ cannot both have a constant term, so one must be in $(x,y)$.  So $(x,y)$ is prime.

We could have deferred to the fact that all maximal ideals are prime.  Also, Sebastian's answer is probably more practical (it is surely how I would approach this problem).  However, sometimes I like seeing definitions work and thought others might as well.