# Maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z$ that is not maximal in $\Bbb Z[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Can someone come up with an example of a maximal ideal *P* in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that *P[X]* is not maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ - the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients?

I know that the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $ p \mathbb{Z}$ where *p* is a prime number but I can't figure out the maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Thanks!

Comment: Question: "for which maximal ideals $(p)$ of $\Bbb Z$ is $(p)$ not maximal in $\Bbb Z[x]$?" Answer: all of them. For further thoughts, consider the fact $M\triangleleft R$ is maximal $\Leftrightarrow R/M$ is a field.

Comment: Okay maybe i didn't formulate my question correctly - a maximal ideal P of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that *P[X]* is not maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Comment: @Katy Edit the question; don't post corrections in the comments.  And the answer is still the same: every single maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is an example.  Hint: $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(p\mathbb{Z})[X]$ is not a field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a maximal ideal $(p)$ of ${\mathbb Z}$, the ideal $(p)$ of ${\mathbb Z}[X]$ is *never* maximal, since ${\mathbb Z}[X]/(p) \cong {\mathbb F}_p[X]$ which is not a field.

For a maximal ideal $(p)$ of ${\mathbb Z}$, the ideal $(p, X)$ is *always* a maximal ideal of ${\mathbb Z}[X]$ for very much the same reason: ${\mathbb Z}[X]/(p,X) \cong {\mathbb F}_p$, which is a field.

In general, the maximal ideals of ${\mathbb Z}[X]$ are of the form $(p,f(X))$, where $p \in {\mathbb Z}$ is prime and $f(X) \in {\mathbb Z}[X]$ is irreducible modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm {\bf Hint}\ \ \  Notice\ that\ the \ ideals \ \ (p) &\subsetneq&\rm (p,x)&\subsetneq&\rm (1)\ \ are\ distinct\ \  \,primes\ \ [or\ (1)]\\ 
\rm because\ their\ residue\ rings\  \ \ \Bbb F_p[x] &\supsetneq&\ \ \, \Bbb F_p&\supsetneq&\rm   (0)\ \ are\ distinct\  domains\ [or\ (0)]\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Similarly for  $(x)\subset (x,y) \subset (1)= \Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19372/242) $\ \ $