# Why $ \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not Principal Ideal Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> $ \mathbf{Z}[x]$ is not PID.

we know $\mathbb Z$ is a Unique Factorization Domain, so $\mathbb Z[x]$ is UFD, but why isn't it PID (since I think $\mathbb Z$ is PID)?

Comment: Consider the ideal $(2,x)$.

Comment: Another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500254/is-mathbbzx-a-principal-ideal-domain

Comment: @SpamIAm but (2,x) is principle in Q[x] right? then what should be the element generating the ideal?

Comment: @annimal Who said anything about $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?  And no element can generate the ideal, so what do you mean by "should"?

Comment: @Slade: I think he means $\langle 2, x \rangle$ is principal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so what is the generator for that ideal? The confusion, I think, arises from the fact that $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Q}$, but not in $\mathbb{Z}$. (In fact, the ideal $\langle 2,x \rangle$ is the entire ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$!)

Comment: $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, hence generates the entire ring.  The idea is to show that $(2,x)$ is *not* a principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: @SpamIAm sorry, I'm asking a new question, why (2,x) is principle in Q[x] ?

Comment: @SpamIAm OK thanks

Comment: @annimal read the earlier comments. $(2,x)$ is generated by $1$ in $Q[x]$.

Answer (score 9):

If it were a PID, then every nonzero prime ideal would be maximal. But $\mathbb Z[X]/p \mathbb Z[X] = \mathbb (Z/p\mathbb Z)[X]$ is an integral domain which is not a field.

Comment: @user26857 I guess not. I hadn't seen that answer.

Comment: Well, I've posted a [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500254/is-mathbbzx-a-principal-ideal-domain) under this question more or less for that answer.

Comment: @user26857 Ok. I didn't read the comments.

Comment: @user26857 See also the [more general theorem,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/91607/242) and see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/361258/18880), both back in the glory days of the site.

Comment: See [this $2011$ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19372/242) for a clearer way to present such arguments.